# JS files are not getting loaded in modal view after once opened

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have created two forms `list.php` and `add.php` in Codeigniter.
In `list.php` I have added bootstrap modal and in that modal, I am loading `add.php` view which contains multiple js files including SELECT2.

**Problem:**
When the user clicks on the add button on `list.php` and close the modal form and again click on add button, all the js files have vanished, i.e. select2 is also not initialized and other js are also not initialized.

**Question:**
What can I do to fix the issue? I have tried putting js files in `view.php` but then it does not work at all.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).